# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

Can some help me why below is thrown

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.jaxb.model.copy.copy.Snapshot nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:588)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:482)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaxb.model.copy.copy.Demo.main(Demo.java:29)

Demo class

```
package com.jaxb.model.copy.copy;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.jaxb.model.copy.copy");

        Snapshot snapshot = new Snapshot();


        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(snapshot, System.out);
    }

}
```

Objectfactory class

```
package com.jaxb.model.copy.copy;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://soma/201407",name="bar")
    public JAXBElement<Foo.Detail.Bar> createBar(Foo.Detail.Bar bar) {
        return new JAXBElement<Foo.Detail.Bar>(new QName("bar"), Foo.Detail.Bar.class, bar);
    }

}
```

Snapshot class
    package com.jaxb.model.copy.copy;

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.guthyrenker.soma.ws.rest.v1.adapter.JsonDateTimeSerializer;
/**
 * @author Srinivasa Kankipati
 * @since 1.0
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = { "mask", "xmlns", "currentAsOf","foo" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "snapshot")
public class Snapshot
{
    @XmlAttribute
    public String mask;

    @XmlElement
    public Date currentAsOf;

    @XmlAttribute
    @JsonIgnore
    public String xmlns;

    @XmlElement(name = "foo")
    private Foo foo;

    public String getMask() {
        return mask;
    }

    public void setMask(String mask) {
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    public Date getCurrentAsOf() {
        return currentAsOf;
    }

    public void setCurrentAsOf(Date currentAsOf) {
        this.currentAsOf = currentAsOf;
    }

    public String getXmlns() {
        return xmlns;
    }

    public void setXmlns(String xmlns) {
        this.xmlns = xmlns;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }



}
```

Foo class

```
package com.jaxb.model.copy.copy;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

import com.guthyrenker.soma.ws.rest.v1.model.ObjectFactory;
import com.guthyrenker.soma.ws.rest.v1.model.WSMarketingOfferOP;
import com.guthyrenker.soma.ws.rest.v1.model.WSMarketingOfferWEB;
import com.jaxb.model.copy.Snapshot;
import com.jverstry.annotations.generics.Market;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Snapshot.class})
public class Foo {

    @XmlElement
    protected Detail detail;

    public Detail getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "bar"})
    public static class Detail
    {
        @XmlElementRef(name="bar")
        private JAXBElement<Foo.Detail.Bar> bar;


            public JAXBElement<Foo.Detail.Bar> getBar() {
            return bar;
        }


        public void setBar(JAXBElement<Foo.Detail.Bar> bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }




        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "value" })
            public static class Bar
            {

                 @XmlAttribute
                 protected String baz;

                 @XmlValue
                    protected BigDecimal value;

                    public String getBaz() {
                        return baz;
                    }

                    public void setBaz(String baz) {
                        this.baz = baz;
                    }

                    public BigDecimal getValue() {
                        return value;
                    }

                    public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
                        this.value = value;
                    }
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current set up your `JAXBContext` would not be aware of your `Snapshot` class.  When you create your `JAXBContext` on a context path, JAXB will first create metadata for the classes referenced from the `ObjectFactory` (or listed in a `jaxb.index` file),  then it will pull in each class it can transitively reach.

You could do the following:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class, Snapshot.class);
```

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks for the help, the above code is sample, but i have same issue when marshelling is done through below code, where build() method will return the response to the browser, getting the same issue, dont know how to resolve the above issue? Response.status(Status.OK).entity(snapshot).build(); import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

Comment: @user3157090 - I have added an answer to your corresponding question about JAX-RS:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23703297/383861